# Can free bitcoins from faucets be actually spent?

Tags: transaction-fees, sending, dust, satoshi

Suppose that I have a wallet with 0.001 bitcoins, from dozens of micro transactions (6000 satoshi in average). That means if I want to spend them, it must be concatenated and the transaction fee would be higher than the actual value?

Comment: There's a [No forced TX Fee](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=22434.5) version of bitcoin client that (as name says) do not enforce any fee on transactions. 
Note, however, that miners might be quite unwilling to include such transaction is their blocks, so there's the chance the transaction will never be processes.

Comment: it will *never* be processed, or it will just have a slow processing time? (days?)

Comment: If it isn't processed, it can't also be canceled, right?

Comment: It _will_ be processed slow, and might even be never processed (and you can't cancel transaction). So that's quite a risky way.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider creating a new address with 0.01 BTC on it, then sending the concatenated amount at 0 trx fee to each of the addresses containing the smaller amounts.

So:

- 0.01 -> first address
- First address (now including the 0.01) -> second address
- second address (now including the 0.01+first address -> third address

... ad nauseum.